# Retrieving a full number

Tags: python, integer

Assume I have a string as follows: `expression = '123 + 321'`.

I am walking over the string character-by-character as follows: `for p in expression`. I am I am checking if `p` is a digit using `p.isdigit()`. If `p` is a digit, I'd like to grab the whole number (so grab `123` and `321`, not just `p` which initially would be `1`).

How can I do that in Python?

In C (coming from a C background), the equivalent would be:

```
int x = 0;
sscanf(p, "%d", &x);
// the full number is now in x
```

**EDIT:**

Basically, I am accepting a mathematical expression from a user that accepts positive integers, +,-,*,/ as well as brackets: '(' and ')'. I am walking the string character by character and I need to be able to determine whether the character is a digit or not. Using `isdigit()`, I can that. If it is a digit however, I need to grab the whole number. How can that be done?

Comment: For a quick and dirty solution, see my remarks on `eval`. A complete answer might involve stacks, parsing, and some mathematical tokenizing. I'd go with `eval` if possible.

Comment: I'm already using stacks and parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python documentation includes a section on [simulating `scanf`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#simulating-scanf), which gives you some idea of how you can use regular expressions to simulate the behavior of `scanf` (or `sscanf`, it's all the same in Python). In particular, `r'\-?\d+'` is the Python string that corresponds to the regular expression for an integer. (`r'\d+'` for a nonnegative integer.) So you could embed this in your loop as

```
integer = re.compile(r'\-?\d+')
for p in expression:
    if p.isdigit():
        # somehow find the current position in the string
        integer.match(expression, curpos)
```

But that still reflects a very C-like way of thinking. In Python, your iterator variable `p` is really just an individual character that has actually been pulled out of the original string and is standing on its own. So in the loop, you don't naturally have access to the current position within the string, and trying to calculate it is going to be less than optimal.

What I'd suggest instead is using Python's built in regexp matching iteration method:

```
integer = re.compile(r'\-?\d+') # only do this once in your program

all_the_numbers = integer.findall(expression)
```

and now `all_the_numbers` is a list of string representations of all the integers in the expression. If you wanted to actually convert them to integers, then you could do this instead of the last line:

```
all_the_numbers = [int(s) for s in integer.finditer(expression)]
```

Here I've used `finditer` instead of `findall` because you don't have to make a list of all the strings before iterating over them again to convert them to integers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was looking for an answer where it describes what's "natural" in Python. I guess I need to steer away from my low-level C mentality when working in Python, since its actually inefficient when working in Python.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good way to approach Python (looking for what's natural) because even in the Python standard library, there are a lot of functions provided that do fairly high-level operations for you. And in a number of ways, Python is just less "explicit" than C - for example, this style of iterating over the individual elements of a thing rather than over their indices within the thing.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> expression = '123 + 321'
>>> expression = ''.join(expression.split()) # strip whitespace
>>> for k, g in groupby(expression, str.isdigit):
        if k: # it's a digit
            print 'digit'
            print list(g)
        else:
            print 'non-digit'
            print list(g)


digit
['1', '2', '3']
non-digit
['+']
digit
['3', '2', '1']
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those problems that can be approached from many different directions. Here's what I think is an elegant solution based on `itertools.takewhile`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, takewhile
>>> def get_numbers(s):
...     s = iter(s)
...     for c in s:
...         if c.isdigit():
...             yield ''.join(chain(c, takewhile(str.isdigit, s)))
... 
>>> list(get_numbers('123 + 456'))
['123', '456']
```

This even works inside a list comprehension:

```
>>> def get_numbers(s):
...     s = iter(s)
...     return [''.join(chain(c, takewhile(str.isdigit, s)))
...             for c in s if c.isdigit()]
... 
>>> get_numbers('123 + 456')
['123', '456']
```

Looking over other answers, I see that this is not dissimilar to [jamylak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12327091/577088)'s `groupby` solution. I would recommend that if you don't want to discard the extra symbols. But if you do want to discard them, I think this is a bit simpler.

Comment: For some reason, it keeps saying `chain` is undefined even though I improted `itertools`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the import line. Try `from itertools import chain, takewhie`.

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm not familiar with `sscanf`, I'm no C developer, it looks like it's using format strings in a way not dissimilar to what I'd use python's `re` module for.  Something like this:

```
import re

nums = re.compile('\d+')
found = nums.findall('123 + 321')
# if you know you're only looking for two values.
left, right = found
```

Comment: Problem with regexp is that they have a steep learning curve and I'm not willing really to learn them at the moment. Also, the expression is unknown to me. It could be `(111 * 302) / 32`. I need to figure out if `p` is a number or an operator.

Comment: @Darksky: You're setting yourself up for a world of hurt in the form of painful string parsing if you don't want to learn regex. You really only need `\d` (digits) and a character class of operators (e.g., `[\/*-+]`). Searching for "Regex math expression" yields plenty of off-the-shelf code with good explanation on SO.

Comment: @Darksky:  Why not code this in C?  You can always come back to Python when you're ready to take the time to learn it.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski already done that in C. I am writing a prefixer (converts infix expressions into prefix expressions). I am doing it in Python as I'm learning Python - thought it'd be a good exercise. But I guess I need to learn regexp either way. I am looking it up at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shlex` http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html

```
>>> from shlex import shlex
>>> expression = '123 + 321'
>>> for e in shlex(expression):
...     print e
... 
123
+
321

>>> expression = '(92831 * 948) / 32'
>>> for e in shlex(expression):
...     print e
... 
(
92831
*
948
)
/
32
```

Answer (score 0):

```
e_array = expression.split('+')
i_array = map(int, e_array)
```

And `i_array` holds all integers in the expression.

---

UPDATE

If you already know all the special characters in your expression and you want to eliminate them all

```
import re

e_array = re.split('[*/+\-() ]', expression)  # all characters here is mult, div, plus, minus, left- right- parathesis and space
i_array = map(int, filter(lambda x: len(x), e_array))
```

Comment: What if I do not know the expression beforehand? All I know is that I have a correct mathematical expression. Could be: `(92831 * 948) / 32`. I am walking the whole expression character by character at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the string up on the `' + '` string, giving you what's outside of them:

```
>>> expression = '123 + 321'
>>> ex = expression.split(' + ')
>>> ex
['123', '321']
>>> int_ex = map(int, ex)
>>> int_ex
[123, 321]
>>> sum(int_ex)
444
```

It's dangerous, but you could use `eval`:

```
>>> eval('123 + 321')
444
```

I'm just taking a stab at you parsing the string, and doing raw calculations on it.

Comment: This probably won't do me much as I am accepting an expression from a user which can be as long as they want, and can include any positive integers, +, -, *, / as well as brackets, ( and ).

Comment: You're asking more than what your question implies. Perhaps you'd like to update it?

Comment: How is `eval` unsuited for your task? Are you on the web?

Comment: I am not looking to evaluate the outcome.. I am looking to parse the expression.